# Is it possible to prevent/remove any cached script declared by dojo.require?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm encountering an issue where most of a page's main logic is offset in a JS file and initialized within a dojo.require call to simplify debugging and development. We're encountering a case where an offload to another page, and then back to the first one and nothing inside our require script loads. I understand this is due in part to how dojo.require re-uses cached pages, but I can't go back to the cached version either. Is there a way, besides pasting all the scripts inside the page itself, to force Dojo to reload any require regardless of if it has been cached or not?

Answer (score 3):

Force it to be reloaded in HTML.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/my/module/name.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      ...
      dojo.require("my.module.name");
      ...
    </script>
```

I don't know if there is any problem on doing it but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you can't do this the "right" way, by putting the relevant code inside a function and then just calling said function again whenever you want?

---

If you still think you need to mess with the module loader though I think there are two alternatives after a quick check on the dojo.require source code:

1. Try to manually clear the module cache

   ```
   delete d._loadedModules['my.module.name'];
   ```
2. Directly call the internal loader:

   ```
   var relpath = d._getModuleSymbols(moduleName).join("/") + '.js';
   d._loadPath(relpath, null);
   ```

(Try these at your own risk)

Comment: I went ahead and re-implemented said code within functions. Thanks.